# Anyone noticed that good questions on new topics are about as easy to close as mediocre questions on beaten to death topics?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110521/how-do-references-work-in-r)

I'm just going to be blunt about my opinion here: I produced a well-researched, clear question with several examples pointing out why a universal programming concept was confounding me in this particular terrain. It is utterly ridiculous for this question to be closed when we allow in deluges of questions just barely useful and intelligent in the "I'm the 1,000,000th visitor to learn how pointers work" camp. For instance, I took the time - about twenty minutes - to post this to StackOverflow because I was confounded that there was not an answer to this easily accessible to me, and **that's what StackOverflow is for.**

In other words, I feel like I just got a C- in a science class at MIT, when plenty of students getting Bs in community college intro courses are soaring past me, because that's exactly the effect that is going on here with question quality.

Yes I'm in rant territory. Sorry. I've seen plenty of content here regarding where to flip the bad questions, this debate we have regarding being generally nice and welcome but not letting the quality help SO offers deteriorate, etc. I've not seen much posts complaining about *this* side of the problem so I estimated the rant would be useful.

Yes, a recourse would be helpful but unfortunately the community mechanisms worked exactly as designed.

White flag. Starting to believe I've graduated asking questions that are basic or redundant enough to be appropriate here.

Comment: Frankly, reading that question, it sounds like a rant against R up to the last line, where you turn it into a question at the last moment. It mainly sounds like you're complaining about the language, and how little sense it makes. I have never used R, so I'm completely impartial, but I could see it turning into an opinion based argument if people do not share your perception of the language.

Comment: BTW, I think that the you absolutely have content for a good question there, and that you should be able to get it re-opened if you reword it. If you can just make it sound less like "R sucks", and put the emphasis on wanting to understand concepts you find unclear, you should be all good.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I definitely think it's legit to say "I'm used to languages X Y and Z which are very sensible in this matter, R is different, what am I missing?" but it's helpful for you to point out that reading. I could try it, obviously I'm soured for putting work into that mini-cesspool for, say, the evening.

Comment: Threw in this edit which hopefully incorporates Reto's point http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24110521/revisions

Comment: @djechlin: I think for the second line of code in your last example you meant  `y <- x <= 5`, which does indeed work.

Comment: I just gave up on that question. I'll learn this within the next week or two, then just kind of know it and not really post it anywhere useful.

Comment: @djechlin I'm just trying to explain that it was a simple typographical error (try mentally substituting for y and you'll see it) and didn't have anything at all to do with references or the data.frame lines. It's possible that the rest of the question could be adapted into a good question but as it is I don't understand what it's asking since there's no unexpected behavior examples.

Comment: Clicked the link up top. Got "this question was voluntarily removed by the author."  What am I supposed to see?

Comment: @Paul Users with >10,000 rep can [view deleted posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). I'm assuming it's for them.

Comment: @Paul: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qhf9p.png

Comment: Thanks, this was useful in my decision to delete my answer here on meta.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't been an active SO member long, so don't give this too much weight, but I'm going to attempt an answer here.

From what I've seen, well-researched and formatted questions will always be respected, as long as they are phrased correctly.

The reason why such "basic questions" (as you call them) are allowed to remain is because no one is moved enough by them to take action.

Now, given I don't have enough rep to view deleted questions, I can't exactly tell first-hand how your question was phrased. However, from the comments on this post, it seems like it was posed as a general rant against a language, which won't be accepted by the community, even if you rebound at the end and turn it into a question.

A high quality question, as I see it, should have five things:

- Good formatting
- Use as a future reference
- Considerable research and background
- Examples

And most importantly:

- A friendly tone

No matter how well the question fulfills the first four, if it has an angry or arrogant tone, it's going to be downvoted and possibly closed.

Despite the fact that, from what I've read on Meta, this site is in some sort of decline (although that's arguable), a friendly and respectful tone is still incredibly important for a good question.